# Как выровнять блоки с текстом?

Tags: html, css

Нужно расположить блоки таким образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только вот не знаю, как правильно сделать. Взять 2 блока родителя по 50% и в них располагать, или же можно как-то иначе?

Вот что у меня получается без блоков-родителей.

```css
.contbody {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}
.contbody h4 {
  color: #4a275c;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.txtbody {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.txtbody p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #090213;
}
.txtbody p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.txtbody p:before {
  content: "\2714";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contbody">
  <h4>Общие параметры линейки :</h4>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Интегрированная компрессорная станция с адсорбционным осушителем и грамотной системой управления и диагностики представляет собой абсолютно новый стандарт качества производства сжатого воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>В результате удобной установки деталей в общем корпусе была создана интегрированная компоновка компрессорной станции, легко подключаемой к потребителям воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Современные и высокоэффективные компоненты (новый блок 5-го поколения A150).</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно ли в моём случае выровнять их как на картинке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пожалуй, только, родитель типа `col` поможет:

Пример:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contbody {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}
.contbody h4 {
  color: #4a275c;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.col {
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
}
.txtbody p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #090213;
}
.txtbody p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.txtbody p:before {
  content: "\2714";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
}

.col:nth-of-type(2n+1){
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="contbody">
  <h4>Общие параметры линейки :</h4>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Интегрированная компрессорная станция с адсорбционным осушителем и грамотной системой управления и диагностики представляет собой абсолютно новый стандарт качества производства сжатого воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>В результате удобной установки деталей в общем корпусе была создана интегрированная компоновка компрессорной станции, легко подключаемой к потребителям воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Современные и высокоэффективные компоненты (новый блок 5-го поколения A150).</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Еще вариант с `inline-block`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contbody {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}
.contbody h4 {
  color: #4a275c;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.col {
  width: 47%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.txtbody p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #090213;
}
.txtbody p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.txtbody p:before {
  content: "\2714";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contbody">
  <h4>Общие параметры линейки :</h4>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Интегрированная компрессорная станция с адсорбционным осушителем и грамотной системой управления и диагностики представляет собой абсолютно новый стандарт качества производства сжатого воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>В результате удобной установки деталей в общем корпусе была создана интегрированная компоновка компрессорной станции, легко подключаемой к потребителям воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Современные и высокоэффективные компоненты (новый блок 5-го поколения A150).</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Вариант с `flex`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contbody {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.contbody h4 {
  color: #4a275c;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.col {
  width: 47%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.txtbody p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #090213;
}
.txtbody p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.txtbody p:before {
  content: "\2714";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contbody">
  <h4>Общие параметры линейки :</h4>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Интегрированная компрессорная станция с адсорбционным осушителем и грамотной системой управления и диагностики представляет собой абсолютно новый стандарт качества производства сжатого воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>В результате удобной установки деталей в общем корпусе была создана интегрированная компоновка компрессорной станции, легко подключаемой к потребителям воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Современные и высокоэффективные компоненты (новый блок 5-го поколения A150).</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Да, но посмотрите на картинке, там слева один большой блок - справа два маленьких.

Comment: Там не очищается обтекание. Тогда для них нужно делать два родителя?

Comment: Точно), на Ваш пример ориентировалась и не увидела еще абзац) sorry

Comment: @Александр, немножко исправила ответ, но все варианты с обертками.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с использованием - [columns](https://webref.ru/css/columns)

```css
.contbody-container{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}
.contbody {  
  -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
}
.contbody h4 {
  color: #4a275c;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.txtbody{}
.txtbody p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #090213;
}
.txtbody p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.txtbody p:before {
  content: "\2714";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contbody-container"> 
<h4>Общие параметры линейки :</h4>
<div class="contbody">  
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Интегрированная компрессорная станция с адсорбционным осушителем и грамотной системой управления и диагностики представляет собой абсолютно новый стандарт качества производства сжатого воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Диагностика и управление эксплуатационными режимами для увеличения эффективности и увеличения срока службы.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>В результате удобной установки деталей в общем корпусе была создана интегрированная компоновка компрессорной станции, легко подключаемой к потребителям воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Современные и высокоэффективные компоненты (новый блок 5-го поколения A150).</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>В результате удобной установки деталей в общем корпусе была создана интегрированная компоновка компрессорной станции, легко подключаемой к потребителям воздуха.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txtbody">
    <p>Современные и высокоэффективные компоненты (новый блок 5-го поколения A150).</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```